# How to split this string in JSON data correctly.

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm working on a script that scrapes certain data from Instagram and I'm having trouble processing a particular line of data.

I'm getting the full json dump from here: https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/1001589106/?__a=1

The piece of code in particular that I'm having trouble with is this one:

```
address_json: "{"street_address": "16215 Alton Pkwy", "zip_code": "92618", "city_name": "Irvine, California", "region_name": "", "country_code": "US", "exact_city_match": false, "exact_region_match": false, "exact_country_match": false}",
```

I can 'kinda' get it close to where I want it by using this:

```
j['graphql']['location']['address_json'].split(',')[2]
```

But that will return:

```
 "city_name": "Irvine
```

While I'm actually hoping to get this output:

```
Irvine, California
```

As I'm a relative python newbie I can't figure out how to correctly process this. Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: trying to parse json manually is a lost fight... Try using the `json` module

Comment: Using this fixed it:

        z = json.loads(j['graphql']['location']['address_json'])
        location_country = z['country_code']

Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. Enjoy python

Comment: looks that the output is poorly designed. json should not be dumped in a string inside a json format...